# what is needed to correct this javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to cycle in order between four images a red square then orange then green then orange then red and repeat. it says in the chrome console changeImage() is not defined. thanks for any help
this is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<img id="myImage" src="red.gif" height="10%">

<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Click Me to change light!</button>

<script>
function changeImage() {
 var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
if (image.src.match("red")) {
    image.src = "amber1.gif";
    alert('Get Ready');
} else if (image.src.match("amber1")) {
    image.src = "green.gif";
    alert('Go');
} else if (image.src.match("green")) {
    image.src = "amber2.gif";
    alert('Slow');
} else {
    image.src = "red.gif";
    alert('Stop');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: last `}` missing ... indent your code ...

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing brace at the end of the script block. If you cut out the function body you have this:

```
function changeImage() {
    ...
```

Instead of this:

```
function changeImage() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tested in chrome and a `}` is missing to close the function.

Once I added it, worked. When I clicked the button, I got the "Get Ready" msg and attempted to load amber1.gif

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<img id="myImage" src="red.gif" height="10%">

<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Click Me to change light!</button>

<script>
function changeImage() {
 var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
  if (image.src.match("red")) {
    image.src = "amber1.gif";
    alert('Get Ready');
  } else if (image.src.match("amber1")) {
    image.src = "green.gif";
    alert('Go');
  } else if (image.src.match("green")) {
    image.src = "amber2.gif";
    alert('Slow');
  } else {
    image.src = "red.gif";
    alert('Stop');
  }
} // <--- This one is missing
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this any different from the other answer or the comment?